# Example of kotlin project with shared module for js

Tags: javascript, gradle, kotlin

Since 1.1 Kotlin has support for compiling code to JS. I want to find example of gradle project how to share some code (for example data-models) between js and jvm platforms. Ideally project should have this structure:

- common module (compiles to .js and .class)
- backend module (jvm)
- frontend module (js, managed by webpack)

Comment: https://github.com/yole/kxhtml-isomorphic

Comment: or also http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html#multiplatform-projects